# Как передать параметр функции уже созданному потоку c флагом CREATE_SUSPENDED?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

День добрый. При создании потока все параметры известны, кроме экземпляра класса task. Идея в следующем: создать поток, создать экземпляр класса task, возобновить выполнение потока с параметром task. На момент создания потока task ещё не создан. Как возобновить поток c передачей нового параметра task? Заранее спасибо.

```
private:            
    HANDLE hThread;
 public:
    Task*  task; 
 Worker()
 {

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, task_proc, task, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);//     

 }

void StartWorker(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    task = (Task*)lpParameter;
    ResumeThread(hThread);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, в данном случае лучше `task` не передавать как параметр, а сделать общей переменной, а для исключения одновременного доступа из разных потоков защитить его с помощью мютекса. Передача неинициализированного указателя как параметра бессмысленна и, скорее всего, компилятор вас об этом предупреждал.

Comment: Или передать указатель на данные (структура, простоя переменная - зависит от задачи) - и менять ее. Приостановленный поток, как я представляю ситуацию, УЖЕ получил свои данные...

Comment: Да,примерно так и удалось решить поставленную задачу.Был создан дополнительный класс Wrapper,который хранит ссылку на task,который надо выполнить.Созданный поток изначально проверяет,стало ли поле объекта Wrapper (указатель на task) не NULL.Как только не NULL,поток делает своё дело

Answer (score 1):

Передайте указатель на task. Только не забудьте про `volatile`, иначе изменения одного потока могут оказаться невидимы в другом. А лучше используйте атомарное значение и передавайте указатель на него.

---

Но зачем такие сложности? Можно же просто создать поток когда задача уже будет определена.

Comment: `volatile` никак не гарантирует, что будет прочитано последнее значение. Это указание компилятору, железу `volatile` не указ. Вообще, не нужно упоминать `volatile` в контексте потоков, это очень дурной тон.

Comment: @ixSci в данном случае, железу указ сам факт запуска нового потока. Порожденный поток видит изменения, сделанные родительским потоком на момент запуска - это стандартная гарантия, предоставляемая любой ОС.

Comment: Откуда такая информация? Быстрый «гуглинг» не показал наличия барьеров при вызове `CreateThread`, т.е. я не вижу никаких гарантий.

Comment: @ixSci во-первых, здравый смысл. Без начального барьера новый поток не может прочитать **ни одну** переменную, включая глобальные, а также то что ему передано по ссылке через единственный параметр! Посмотрите любой пример работы с потоками. Если там нет барьера в самом начале потока - значит, неявно предполагается системный.

Comment: @ixSci во-вторых, примерное знание деталей реализации. Я не знаю способа операционной системе переключить контекст выполнения не сделав при этом ни одной операции, приводящей к барьеру.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю задачу, то можно :

1. Создать мьютекс, защищающий task;
2. Захватить мьютекс до создания потока;
3. Создать поток, который первым делом пытается захватить мьютекс,защищающий task;
4. Создать task в основном потоке, отпустить мьютекс.
5. Не забыть освободить мьютекс по окончании бработки task.

Таким образом, новый поток будет висеть в ожидании, пока не создастся task. Правда не очень понятно, зачем такое поведение требуется.